# How to create a root user with no password in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am able to login into mysql using a username & password that I have created.

I ran `SELECT user FROM mysql.user;`

and it shows my created account and 3 instances of root.

1.)  How do I see the passwords for any of the root users?

2.)  If that cannot be down, how do remove those root users, and create a new root user with no password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot see the plain text passwords.

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root' AND host <> 'localhost';
UPDATE mysql.user SET password = '' WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Before doing this, you should run [mysql_secure_installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html).

If you cannot get back in with `root@localhost` and no password, do the following:

```
SQLSTMT="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to root@localhost"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} IDENTIFIED BY 'resetpwd' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
echo ${SQLSTMT} > /var/lib/mysql/init.sql
service mysql restart --init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init.sql
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/init.sql
SQLSTMT="UPDATE mysql.user SET password = '' WHERE user='root'"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} AND host='localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
mysql -uroot -presetpwd -e"${SQLSTMT}"
mysql -uroot
```

Comment: I did this, but when I login using 'mysql -u root' I get the error 'ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' Any thoughts why or what is happening?

Comment: mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET password = '' WHERE user='root';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

Comment: @Nicodemuz From version 5.7 and up please use `DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root' AND 
host <> 'localhost'; UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = '' WHERE user='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to have a root mysql user with blank password!!

However, here is how to do it

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@127.0.0.1=PASSWORD('');
```

please not that you must be logged in to mysql as root!

Comment: Your user must be any user with a `SUPER` privilege.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 instances of `root` will likely be for the host variations. In other words, there might be one for `root@localhost` and one for `root@%`.

If you're using phpMyAdmin you could delete the users you don't want, or reset the passwords by clicking the `Users` tab.

You can check the users you don't want, and click `Go` on `Remove selected users`.

Or to reset the password for a specific user, you can click `Edit privileges`, scroll down to the `Change password` section, select `No password`, and hit `Go`.

You can download phpMyAdmin [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net), and you'll of course need to be logged in as root to do this.

[image: Users]
[image: Reset pass]