# why the database connection symphony dont work?

Tags: database, frameworks, connection, host

i want just to host a website previously work , into another web server
i have change parameters.yml file with new host parameteres of connection
i have upload all my files , and i have import my databases
when i try to enter (myhost/web ) i have this errors : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

error.log

[07-Dec-2022 15:30:13 Africa/Algiers] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home2/icares/logicom.dz/ncomparer/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/icares/logicom.dz/ncomparer/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', NULL, Array)
#1 /home2/icares/logicom.dz/ncomparer/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(45): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', NULL, Array)
#2 /home2/icares/logicom.dz/ncomparer/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'root', NULL, Array)
#3 /home2/icares/logicom.dz/ncomparer/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
#4 /home2/icares/logicom.dz/ncomparer/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(389):  in /home2/icares/logicom.dz/ncomparer/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 3390

I have change the parameters of connection with new server , but the error is that username root password no and server is localhost , what i must do ?

Answer (score 0):

The error.log says that your Symfony trying to access database (probably MySQL) via the user 'root' from a local host. But your database, MySQL is not set to allow access as 'root'.

MySQL and most databases do not allow to access as 'root' as default as security reason, especially without password (what your erro said).

So, may be you need to check:

- What is your database_user and database_password set in Symfony project (parameters.yml?)
- Check MySQL from cli that what kind of previleges are set for your database.

The way to access mysql without password may find here:
[Allow linux root user mysql root access without password](https://serverfault.com/questions/563714/allow-linux-root-user-mysql-root-access-without-password)

Or some hints may be here:
[How to create a root user with no password in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739645/how-to-create-a-root-user-with-no-password-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for answer , my parameters are not using root and local host , they use database host server and username and pass
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: mysql1004.mochahost.com
    database_port: null
    database_name: icares_ncomparer
    database_user: icares_ncomparer
    database_password: ***********
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user: elm3hdi@gmail.com
    mailer_password: **********
    mailer_auth_mode: login
    mailer_port: 587
    mailer_encryption: tls

Comment: Did you check settings in your Symfony project inside parameters.yml?

Comment: yes , have changed to my remote host ; host , username, password I'm not using localhost /root/null

Comment: May be you can find-out what values are currently using by creating a simple, like, MyController.php and then add action to show the paramter values for database.

// src/Controller/MyController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    // ...

    public function index(): Response
    {
        $database_host = $this->getParameter('database_host');
        // ...
    }
}