# Connect to mariaDB with sudo without password

Tags: mariadb

After a fresh installation of MariaDB, the system's user `root` is able to connect as root without password with :
`sudo mysql -u root`

After reimporting my backup, I can't do this anymore :

```
user@server:~$ sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Table `mysql.user` contains :

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select host, user, password, plugin from mysql.user;
+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| host      | user       | password                                  | plugin                |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| localhost | root       |                                           | mysql_native_password |
| localhost | phpmyadmin | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | mysql_native_password |
| %         | user1      | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | mysql_native_password |
| localhost | seafile    | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | mysql_native_password |
| localhost | gogs       | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | mysql_native_password |
| localhost | user2      | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |                       |
| localhost | freshrss   | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |                       |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
7 rows in set (0,001 sec)
```

How can I get back this behaviour ?

I'm using mariadb 10.5 and Debian 11.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why `root` user have empty `password` column. A password is set for this user, too.

Comment: help? [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739645/how-to-create-a-root-user-with-no-password-in-mysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, from MariaDB-10.4 onwards `mysql.user` is a view that doesn't completely contain everything related to the user. `mysql.global_priv` is the more complete version.

For a complete view of a user, use `show create user root@localhost`.

To change use [alter user](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-user/):

```
MariaDB [mysql]> alter user root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA   unix_socket;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> show create user root@localhost;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE USER for root@localhost                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE USER `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: Is it possible to continue to be able to login with password ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846000/enable-password-and-unix-socket-authentication-for-mariadb-root-user says `ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket OR mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD("my-password");` works, but I got an error.

Comment: Like [MDEV-27733](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27733)? Please report bugs if that's not it.

Comment: I get `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: Can you include the `mysql.global_priv` row containing `root` ,`localhost` in a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org) and we'll see what can be done. What MariaDB version was the backup from?